# subform within a subform

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

I'm working on a model using Zend Form. I have a subform called $product_item. I would like to add multiple instances of it to another subform called $items. How would I go about doing that? I'm not finding the Zend reference guide particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add sub-forms to sub-forms:-

```
$form = new Application_Form_Test();
$subForm1 = new Application_Form_TestSubForm();
$subForm2 = new Application_Form_TestSubForm();
$subForm1->addSubForm($subForm2, 'sub2');
$form->addSubForm($subForm1, 'sub1');
$this->view->form = $form;
```

On submission the subform values will be available in arrays in the `$_POST` array. `$value=$_POST['sub1']['sub2']['name']` for example.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms

To print or access elements in sub forms you have several options:-

If `$subForm1` has an element declared thus:-

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
```

Then the `email` field can be rendered in the view like this:-

```
<?php echo $this->element->sub1->email; ?>
```

Remember that the elements are referenced by their *names* not by the variables you use to declare them.

Also, remember that `$this->element` is referencing an instance of `Zend_Form` so you have all of those methods available. That means you can do this:-

```
<?php
    $form = $this->element;
    $formElements = $form->getElements();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. A follow up if I may... I know you can print a normal form element in the view like so: `<?= $this->element->email;?>`. If $email is an element of $subForm1, how would you print it?

Comment: Update: Figured it out: `$this->element->sub1->sub2->email;`